# stoping flash file from running more than one time

Tags: asp.net, flash

I am working with a flash-template to create a website. I have a master page with a flash header and flash menu. when my home pages runs the flash header runs. the flash file should just run once but it is running each time I click on the menu items. I tried to use updatepanel, but i didn't know how to set the updatemode since my menu is working with flash. any idea of what i should use???

Answer (score 1):

Store some data in the client that says they've viewed the flash before. When you execute your flash file, check for the existence of this data, and react accordingly. You may want to peak at http://www.flash-db.com/Tutorials/saving/ on how to save data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use local storage, as shown [here](http://drawlogic.com/2008/01/10/howto-sharedobjects-for-local-storage-as3/) :

Write it as :

```
import flash.net.SharedObject;
var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("userData");
so.data.isUsed= "true";
so.flush(); // writes changes to disk
```

Read it as :

```
import flash.net.SharedObject;
var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("userData");
var isUsed = so.data.isUsed;
```

---

If it's a website page you may also use [ExternalInterface.addCallback](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#addCallback%28%29) to add a function which can be called from javascript.